# git repository on github

Tags: git, github

someone just shared a git repository with me (I can now see the shared repository under account settings/repositories) so that I can change files and commit those changes to the live server.

I'm not quite sure how to commit changes from this shared repository to the live server however. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`git push`](http://progit.org/book/ch2-5.html#pushing_to_your_remotes) or [send a pull request](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/).

Comment: I have another question - how do we deploy commits to the live server using git? I committed to the shared repository but it is not showing on the live server... is there an additional step?

Comment: What live server? What shared repo? Are we still talking about github here? I have no idea how any part of your system is set up. You might want to ask a new question, or ask the person who shared the git repo with you.

Comment: Got it. I have a question - what is the difference between creating a "branch" and cloning a repository? What is the benefit of branching?

Comment: They are completely different things. Again, this is a rather separate question from your original so I would recommend just asking a new one (e.g. click the `Ask Question` button). Or you can start by reading one of the many SO questions on Git, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916849/.